# Play 2.0 not auto-reloading

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

My Play 2.0 test application dose not seem to auto-reload after I change some files. The console shows `[info] Compiling 1 Java source to /java/todolist/target/scala-2.9.1/classes...` when I change + save a file, but the the content in the browser stays unchanged. Play is running in Dev mode with auto-reloading enabled.

Console output:

```
$ play run
[info] Loading project definition from /data/dev/java/todolist/project
[info] Set current project to todolist (in build file:/data/dev/java/todolist/)

--- (Running the application from SBT, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] play - Listening for HTTP on port 9000...

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)

[info] play - Application started (Dev)
[info] Compiling 1 Java source to /data/dev/java/todolist/target/scala-2.9.1/classes...
```

Comment: How do you start your application in the Play console? Try starting it with `~ run` instead of `run` (notice the tilde).

Comment: we need more information on the console output, paths you are using, etc

Comment: @tmbrggmn Unfortunatly that dose not help, the problem persists.

Comment: @PereVillega Just updated the post ... hope it helps!

Comment: The command `play clean` seems to fix the problem. No idea why ...

Comment: @wowpatrick I was going to suggest that, using Play clean, to remove hte cache of compiled classes. You solved it, good! Please add that as an answer and accept it for future reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `play clean` and restart your Play application and Play should start auto-reloading the files on the next startup.